# Trouble with java logic in if else statements

Tags: java

I have a very simple problem at [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/51fda2d95d6efda45e00004e/train/java). **Debug for fun** . Here goes!

> Write a class called **User** that is used to calculate the amount
> that a user will progress through a ranking system similar to the one
> Codewars uses.
>
> **Business Rules:**
>
> A user starts at rank -8 and can progress all the way to 8.
>
> **There is no 0 (zero) rank**. The next rank after -1 is 1.
>
> Users will complete **activities**. **These activities also have
> ranks**. Each time the user completes a ranked activity the users rank
> progress is updated based off of the activity's rank.
>
> **The progress earned from the completed activity is relative to what the user's current rank is compared to the rank of the activity**
>
> A user's rank progress starts off at zero, each time the progress
> reaches 100 the user's rank is upgraded to the next level
>
> Any remaining progress earned while in the previous rank will be
> applied towards the next rank's progress (we don't throw any progress
> away). The exception is if there is no other rank left to progress
> towards (Once you reach rank 8 there is no more progression).
>
> A user **cannot progress beyond rank 8**.
>
> The only acceptable range of rank values is
> `-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` Any other value should raise
> an error. The progress is scored like so:
>
> - Completing an activity that is ranked the same as that of the user's
>   will be worth 3 points
> - Completing an activity that is ranked one ranking lower than the
>   user's will be worth 1 point
> - Any activities completed that are ranking 2 levels or more lower
>   than the user's ranking will be ignored
> - Completing an activity ranked higher than the current user's rank
>   will accelerate the rank progression. The greater the difference
>   between rankings the more the progression will be increased. The
>   formula is 10 * d * d where d equals the difference in ranking
>   between the activity and the user.
>
> **Logic Examples:**
>
> - If a user ranked **-8** completes an activity ranked **-7** they will    receive 10 progress
> - If a user ranked **-8** completes an activity ranked **-6** they will    receive 40 progress
> - If a user ranked **-8** completes an activity ranked **-5** they will    receive 90 progress
> - If a user ranked **-8** completes an activity ranked **-4** they will    receive 160 progress, resulting in the user being upgraded to
>   rank -7    and having earned 60 progress towards their next rank
> - If a user ranked **-1** completes an activity ranked **1** they will    receive 10 progress **(remember, zero rank is ignored)**

Here is my solution

```
public class User {
int rank = -8;
int progress = 0;
public User() {

}

public int getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public void setRank(int rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
}

public int getRankProgress() {
    return progress;
}

public void setRankProgress(int progress) {
    this.progress = progress;
}

public void updateRank() {
    while (progress >= 100) {
        int newRank = this.rank + 1;
        if (rank == -1) {
            newRank = 1;
        } else if (rank == 8) {
            return;
        }
        setRank(newRank);
        setRankProgress(progress - 100);
    }
}

public void incProgress(int activityRank) {
    if (activityRank < -8 || activityRank == 0 || activityRank > 8) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    System.out.println("Called with activity rank " + activityRank + " user rank " + getRank());
    if (activityRank == getRank()) {
        setRankProgress(progress + 3);
    } else if (getRank() > activityRank && getRank() - activityRank == 1) {
        setRankProgress(progress + 1);
    } else if (getRank() > activityRank && getRank() - activityRank >= 2) {
        return;
    } else if (activityRank > getRank()) {
        System.out.println("Called 5");
        int d;
        if (activityRank >= 0 && getRank() < 0) {
            d = (activityRank - getRank()) - 1;
        } else {
            d = activityRank - getRank();
        }

        int progress = 10 * d * d;
        setRankProgress(progress);
    }
    updateRank();
}

}
```

I think my logic is correct but i still get an error:

> After applying rank of 1 the resulting user rank was expected to be -1, but was actually -2 expected:<-1> but was:<-2>

Comment: Please include the initial User state (rank and progress) as this determines how the activity rank of 1 should be processed.

Comment: @sp00m . It must be broken because there I've tried close to everything

Comment: @vsfDawg please explain more

Comment: @AmosMachora  The User has two attributes - rank and progress.  What are the initial values for these attributes when the test is executed?

Comment: @vsfDawg the rank is -8 and the progress is 0

Comment: I've got it to pass with my own code. Some hints after looking at your code: when you compare two ranks, i.e. in `getRank() - activityRank == 1`, if `getRank()` is `1` and `activityRank` is `-1`, then `1` is expected instead of `2`, given rank 0 doesn't exist. In `setRankProgress(progress);` after you calculate `10 * d * d`, you forgot to add it to the existing `this.progress`. In `updateRank()`, you set `newRank` to `1` if the current `rank` is `-1`, but it's when the current `rank` is `0` that you needs to increment. In that same method, if `rank` is `8`, `progress` must be forced to `0`.

Comment: Hand calculating the case (User(rank=-8, progress=0), activityRank=1):  Rank difference is 8 so you should generate 10 * 8 * 8 progress which is 640.  This should raise the user rank from -8 to -2 with 40 progress remaining.  It sounds like the test assertion is wrong.  There are flaws in your logic but they are unrelated to this case (see sp00m's comment above).  Consider calculating the rank difference once and then switching on the difference.